# KeyError: '-1' when adding field and calculating expression with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, pyqt4, keyerror

I want to use PyQGIS to add a new field and calculate the values for each feature. Similar to the Field Calculator option.

My 'Field Calculator' expression is for example: `y(start_point($geometry))`

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import QgsField, QgsExpression, QgsFeature

vl = iface.activeLayer()

vl.startEditing()

#step 1
myField = QgsField( 'myNewColumn', QVariant.Float )
vl.addAttribute( myField )
idx = vl.fieldNameIndex( 'myNewColumn' )

#step 2
e = QgsExpression( 'y(start_point($geometry))' )
e.prepare( vl.pendingFields() )

for f in vl.getFeatures():
    f[idx] = e.evaluate( f )
    vl.updateFeature( f )

vl.commitChanges()
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/var/folders/0r/q6nxg6w54fv4l7c8gksb2t500000gn/T/tmp9dosIe.py", line 30, in <module>
    f[idx] = e.evaluate( f )
KeyError: '-1'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error you get says the field index is `-1`, so your new field wasn't found in your attribute table.

That may be happening because:

1. You need to use `QVariant.Double` instead of `QVariant.Float`.
2. You've not committed the new field to the layer provider before asking for your new column index.
3. You're asking for the index of `myNewColumn` but your provider can only store 10 characters for field names, so it has stored `myNewColum` (missing final `n`). (Just happened to me while giving the answer a try)

Try this instead:

```
# Step 1
myField = QgsField('newColumn', QVariant.Double)
vl.dataProvider().addAttributes([myField])
vl.updateFields()
idx = vl.fields().indexOf('newColumn')
```

Now `idx` should be different than `-1`, you can check it:

```
if idx != -1:
    print("Field found!")
```

By the way, you can run the `#step 1` code out of the edit block.

Comment: After some basic testing I think its the character limit of the field name. Of course sending 'x coord' to an QVariant.Int isn't a good idea too, no error though, just bad programming. Double should be there. thanks

Comment: To be honest, it's the first time I face such problem. As always, testing line by line gives you hints on what might be happening.

Comment: Does someone know how to proceed with pyqgis 3 ?

Comment: There you go @wanderzen. I just updated the answer to QGIS v3.x