# How to edit multiple layer simultaneously with Python in QGIS 3.0?

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3

I have many layers but only want to edit several of them in QGIS 3.0

```
layer1 = QgsVectorLayer('...','layer1','ogr')
layer2 = QgsVectorLayer('...','layer2','ogr')
layer3 = QgsVectorLayer('...','layer3','ogr')
layer4 = QgsVectorLayer('...','layer4','ogr')
layer5 = QgsVectorLayer('...','layer5','ogr')
layer6 = QgsVectorLayer('...','layer6','ogr')
layers_edit = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('layer1' and 'layer2' and 'layer3')
```

In every layer an area is given `('area_calc')`

```
sa = layers.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex('area_calc')
```

An error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dataProvider'
```

Making a list of layers and `startEditing()` also doesn't work.

```
layers.startEditing()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startEditing'
```

The next step I want to do is:

```
layers.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField ('eur1_km2',Variant.Double),QgsField('eur1_pol', QVariant.Double)])
layers.updateFields()

idx=layers.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex('eur1_km2') 
idx1=layers.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex('eur1_pol')

for f in layers.getFeatures():
    f[idx] = 6
    attr_sa = f.attributes()[sa]
    attr_idx = f.attributes()[idx]
    f[idx1] = (attr_sa/1000000)*attr_idx
    layers.updateFeature( f )

layers.commitChanges()
```

But the same error occurs. Has anyone an idea how to edit these three layers simultanously with python in QGIS 3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add the changes to my script. Here is the code:

```
layer_edit = ['layer1', 'layer2','layer3']
price = 6.0
for layers in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if layers.name() in layer_edit:
        layers.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField('eur1_km2',QVariant.Double)])
        layers.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField('eur1_pol',QVariant.Double)])
        layers.updateFields()
        idx = layers.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex('eur1_km2')

        layers.startEditing()
        for f in layers.getFeatures():
                f[idx] = price
                layers.updateFeature(f)
                idx = layers.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex('eur1_km2')
                idx1 = layers.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex('eur1_pol')
                sa = layers.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex('area_calc')
                attr_idx = f.attributes()[idx]
                attr_sa = f.attributes()[sa]
                f[idx1]=(attr_sa/1000000*attr_idx)
                layers.updateFeature(f)

        layers.commitChanges()

    else: print('NONE')
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit specific layers, you can insert their names into a list and iterate through these using a `for` loop. You can then add the rest of your script inside the loop to affect each layer in turn:

```
layer_names = ['layer1',  'layer2', 'layer3']

for layers in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if layers.name() in layer_names:
        sa = layers.fields().lookupField('area_calc')
        # do more stuff
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I can now add attributes to the table, but unfortunately I can't fill the table with values. It should look like 'layers.fields().lookupField('name') = 6'. Have you any idea how to add values within the table? (By the way the value is in every table the same).

Comment: You can't fill the tables using the code you wrote from your [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285387/calculate-expression-with-python)? Could you please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/286932/edit) your question to include your new script so that we can see how far it works? :)