# AttributeError when creating list field with QVariant in QgsVectorLayer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, list, pyqt5, attributeerror

I am trying to create a list-type field for the active layer using the code below, which is not working.

Is there any other way to create a list-type field and update the `list([1,2,3])` as an attribute value to the created area?

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

field = 'list_field'
if layer.fields().indexFromName(field) == -1:
    fieldz = QgsField(field , QVariant.list)
    layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([fieldz])
    layer.updateFields()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I could get the same error as you:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'QVariant' has no attribute 'list'
```

This happened due to the wrong specification of the `QVariant` type. It should be `QVariant.List` instead of `QVariant.list`, [see the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qvariant.html#QVariant-21):

```py
from qgis.core import QgsField, QgsVariantUtils
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

new_field = QgsField("ListField", QVariant.List)
print(QgsVariantUtils.typeToDisplayString(new_field.type())) # List
```

So, your code can be adjusted as follows:

```py
from qgis.gui import QgisInterface
from qgis.core import QgsField
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

layer = iface.activeLayer()

field = 'list_field'
if layer.fields().indexFromName(field) == -1:
    fieldz = QgsField(field , QVariant.List)
    layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([fieldz])
    layer.updateFields()
```

However, I would probably proceed in a slightly different manner to create a new field:

```py
from qgis.gui import QgisInterface
from qgis.core import QgsField
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

layer = iface.activeLayer()

field = 'list_field'

if field not in layer.fields().names():
    layer_provider = layer.dataProvider()
    layer_provider.addAttributes([QgsField(field, QVariant.List)])
    layer.updateFields()
```

Also, keep in mind that you may encounter the following error e.g.:

> ```
> Layer <LAYER_NAME>: type for field list_field not found
> ```

---

**References:**

- [KeyError: '-1' when adding field and calculating expression with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/197726/99589)
- [QGIS Python Tutorial: How to Add/Delete Field and Updating Attribute Value](https://www.geodose.com/2018/09/qgis-python-tutorial-add-field-attribute.html)
- [PyQGIS 101: Using expressions to compute new field values](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-using-expressions-to-compute-new-field-values/)